Physical interpretation of the matrix element
In perturbation theory, but also in other scenarios the claim is made that the following expression:
$|\langle f|\hat O||i\rangle|^2$  represents the probability amplitude for a transition of the system from an initial state $|i\rangle$ to a final state $|f\rangle$, caused by some operator $\hat O$.
In the Wikipedia article about the matrix element, the following is said:

Physically, the matrix elements here represent the transition probability amplitude for a particle in state $|i\rangle$ to transition to a state $|f\rangle$ due to the interaction governed by some operator.
(The commentary was made in the context of the Hamilton operator for an unperturbed system, but I figured, the same can be said if we consider an arbitrary operator.)

I want to understand how do we come to the conclusion that $|\langle f|\hat O||i\rangle|^2$ represents or can be interpreted as a probability of transition. What is the argument put forward for this claim?

It's just the usual Born rule. If you have a system prepared in a state $|\psi\rangle$, the probability to find it in state $|\phi\rangle$ is given by $|\langle\phi|\psi\rangle|^2$. Taking now $|\psi\rangle  = \hat O|i\rangle$ and $|\phi\rangle = |f\rangle$, the statement follows immediately.

@paulina:  That looks like an answer to me.

@paulina  Does the Born rule explains why $|\langle \phi|\psi\rangle|^2|$ is interpreted as probability of transition? Considering a system in state $|\psi\rangle=\sum_n c_n|n\rangle$, the probability to measure an eigenvalue $a_n$ (we assume that the state is expressed as lin. combination of basis kets that are eigenstates of an arbitrary op. $\hat O$) is $P(a_n)=|c_n|^2=|\langle n|\psi\rangle|^2$. What we are talking is a generalization of this.

@paulina
The only argument I can think that allows us to interpret  $|\langle \phi|\psi\rangle|^2|$ as probability, is the mathematical interpretation of $|\langle \phi|\psi\rangle|^2$. This is just the projection of a vector into another one. If the vectors are "parallel" then the entire state $|\psi\rangle$ is projected onto $|\phi\rangle$. In qm language that translates as 100% probability of transition.

Well, I cannot understand “caused by some operators”.  Operators do not cause transformations of states. At most it happens when the operator is unitary or anti unitary and represents a symmetry. This is not the case. The interpretation is instead indirect and it is just part of some approximation, like Fermi’s golden rule, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi's_golden_rule where the operator is the (interaction) Hamiltonian, as the quoted text states. The interpretation is not generally valid for other operators.
